# Trying to parse IMAP email with PHP > Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to parse emails sent to "parsethis@mysite.com" with PHP (I will use a cronjob, but for now I am just hitting mysite.com/cronJobs/parseMail in my browser).

This is my first time trying to parse emails  .. so I'm just not sure how to go about troubleshooting this at all.

Here is the code I'm using, found it on a site and it seemed to be something I can work from.  (Yes I have replaced all the placeholders)

```
        $mailbox = imap_open("{mysite.com:143/notls}INBOX", "parsethis@mysite.com", "123password");  //connects to mailbox on your server

        if ($mailbox == false) {
            echo "<p>Error: Can't open mailbox!</p>";
            echo imap_last_error();
        }else{

            //Check number of messages
            $num = imap_num_msg($mailbox);

            //if there is a message in your inbox
            if( $num > 0 ) { //this just reads the most recent email. In order to go through all the emails, you'll have to loop through the number of messages
                $email = imap_fetchheader($mailbox, $num); //get email header

                $lines = explode("\n", $email);

                // data we are looking for
                $from = "";
                $subject = "";
                $to = "";
                $headers = "";
                $splittingheaders = true;

                for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
                    if ($splittingheaders) {
                    // this is a header
                    $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

                    // look out for special headers
                        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
                            $subject = $matches[1];
                        }
                        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
                            $from = $matches[1];
                        }
                        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
                            $to = $matches[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                //We can just display the relevant information in our browser, like below or write some method, that will put that information in a database
                echo "FROM: ".$from."<br>";
                echo "TO: ".$to."<br>";
                echo "SUBJECT: ".$subject."<br>";
                echo "BODY: ".imap_qprint(imap_body($mailbox, $num));

                //delete message
                // imap_delete($mailbox,$num);  // not while testing
                // imap_expunge($mailbox);  // not while testing
            }else{
                // echo "No more messages";
            }
        imap_close($mailbox);
    }
```

Problem is :  I get this when I hit it

```
FROM: "K.K.Smith" 
TO: parsethis@mysite.com 
SUBJECT: test subject 
BODY: --50f9f846_140e0f76_3df1 Content-Type: // etc .. with the body of the email unformatted in a continuous string

// INTERESTING > I get the body twice .. doubled.. once as a long unformatted string, and then again with formatting
--50f9f846_140e0f76_3df1 Content-Type: text/html; // etc.. the rest of the body with formatting .. ie my signature is correctly formatted with spacing and line breaks unlike the first body output

/// ***and then this weird error at the end*** 
--50f9f846_140e0f76_3df1-- 
Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

So I don't know what that means.  I have googled and all results seem to indicate it is a "mysterious error".  It looks like it is about to output the body for a third time (I don't really know what that weird string is.. an email id maybe?)  .. but then it chokes where it didn't choke the two previous times.

.. can anyone give any ideas how I should move forward?

***EDIT***

so I reduced the parseMail function to just the minimum..

```
public function parseMail(){
    $mailbox = imap_open("{mysite.com:143/notls}INBOX", "parsethis@mysite.com", "123password");  //connects to mailbox on your server
    imap_close($mailbox);
}
```

and I still get the error when I hit it.  Ideas?

***SOLVED***

It looks like it has something to do with Codeigniter interpreting errors/warnings thrown by the IMAP functions as exceptions.

My solution was to put this after my imap_close() function

```
imap_errors();
```

This got rid of the error notice for me.

[Here is where i found my solution on the Kohana discussion board](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6371/exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame/p1)

Comment: Related: http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/16

Comment: Well, thank you so much for this. And wtf php.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having the same issue in Laravel 4.2. And this one line of code fixed it.